# asp.net mvc + routelink get only 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

here's my code:

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "snakes",
            url: "snakes-databases/",
            defaults: new { controller = "SnakesController", action = "index" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "snakesLists",
            url: "snakes-databases/{family}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "SnakesController", action = "Lists", family = "" }

        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "snakesDetails",
            url: "snakes-databases/{family}/{species}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "SnakesController", action = "Details", family = "", species = "" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@Html.RouteLink("snakes database", "snakes", null, new { @class = "dropdown-toggle", data_toggle="dropdown"})
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>@Html.RouteLink("Boidae", "snakesLists", new { family = "boidae" })</li>
    <li>@Html.RouteLink("Colubridae", "snakesLists", new { family = "colubridae" })</li>
    <li>@Html.RouteLink("Elapidae", "snakesLists", new { family = "elapidae" })</li>
    <li>@Html.RouteLink("Viperidae", "snakesLists", new { family = "viperidae" })</li>
</ul>
```

SnakeController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Lists(string family)
{
    return View();
}
```

I do not understand why for every url except homepage (/) I get a 404 error.

Comment: Why space in RouteLink "snakes database"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not definening your actions, for the homepage you dont have to do it because that's default the Index action.

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        name: "snakes",
        url: "snakes-databases/{index}",
        defaults: new { controller = "SnakesController", action = "Index" }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "snakesLists",
        url: "snakes-databases/{Lists}/{family}/",
        defaults: new { controller = "SnakesController", action = "Lists", family = "" }

    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "snakesDetails",
        url: "snakes-databases/{Details}/{family}/{species}/",
        defaults: new { controller = "SnakesController", action = "Details", family = "", species = "" }
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Oh you no need to set:

```
controller = "SnakesController"
```

only set it is:

```
controller = "Snakes"
```

All is:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "snakes",
            url: "snakes-databases/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Snakes", action = "index" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "snakesLists",
            url: "snakes-databases/{family}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Snakes", action = "Lists", family = "" }

        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "snakesDetails",
            url: "snakes-databases/{family}/{species}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Snakes", action = "Details", family = "", species = "" }
        );
```

Hope can help you :)